# Do different classes get different weapons?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In ME1 and ME2 classes got specific weapons to use e.g. solider got everything except smg.

With the addition of the load out customization I do not understand whether or not this has been carried over to ME3.

I cannot find anything on the ME wiki about this and would like a more direct source, does it carry over or does it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shepard can take whatever combination of weapons you choose.  Instead of limiting his available weapons, this has been replaced by the "weight" mechanic.

Each weapon has a weight statistic, and the combined weight of your weapon loadout controls how fast your powers recharge.  If you want to focus solely on your armaments and not tech or biotic power, you can take a considerable amount of weapons into battle.

Do note that other squadmates are limited in their weapon choices.  Garrus, for example, will only take a sniper rifle and an assault rifle.

Comment: This is what I found weird, ME has restricted weapons for certain classes and that was the reason I became a soldier, to wield more weapons, which increases ammo capacity all together.

Comment: @SamuelStandrin: But soldiers have few if any offensive skills that don't use a weapon.  Soldiers need more ammo and therefore more weapons because they can't effectively take out enemies with skills alone.

Comment: @MBraedley and now they have made soldier obsolete, unless they have added more abilities to compensate, which I doubt.

Comment: @SamuelStandrin: No, I'm not saying soldiers are obsolete in ME3.  The job of a soldier is to put lots of metal in enemies at any range.  As an Infiltrator, I can't really do that at short range.  As a Vanguard, I can't that at anything but short range.  And as the other three classes, I can't do it at any range.  Just because I can carry any weapon doesn't mean I can handle it.

Comment: @MBraedley so if I am mainly a Assault rifle, Sniper and Pistol user, I use sniper and assault rifle roughly the same amount as each other. Which would be the best class to use these weapons?

Comment: @SamuelStandrin: Sniper riffle and pistol is Infiltrator, sniper riffle, assault riffle and shotgun is Soldier.  Your combination is... odd, but might make sense with a specific group of weapons, namely full auto assault riffles.  Having said that, I will equip that combo as an infiltrator for some select missions where medium range could be a big factor.

Answer (score 0):

As Shepard you can use every weapon, though there are some class-specific abilities that only work with certain weapons (e.g. the time-dilation for sniper rifles that soldiers and infiltrators get). You need to pay some attention to the weight of the weapons, different classes have different weight limits and some weapon classes are generally heavier than others. So for example an adept running around with a sniper rifle and an assault rifle might not be a good idea as your power recharge will suffer a lot.

Your companions are limited to certain class-specific weapons, they can't use just any weapon.

Comment: There is an upgrade (Scope) that gives the time dialation to other classes in a lesser form, for Sniper Rifles.